# Scrolling text in android EditText widget

Tags: android

I have a single line EditText in android which displays a long line of text. Now, the requirement is that when I scroll to the end of line, and keeps on deleting characters using backspace, the text should keep scrolling horizontally as more space is now available. 
After going through other SO questions and other online resources, I have set the following style:

```
<style name="MyEditText" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
        <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    </style>
```

But it does not work. I have seen this behavior in other applications, so I know it works on Android. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> try to add some constraints in the layout of edittext instead defining
>   style

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:ems="5"
            android:maxHeight="40dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" >
```

try this it may help u

Comment: you may use as you wants i have wether horizontal or vertical but in this context it should be vertical as height us fixed to allow scrollbar appears